# Placing an object at bottom of canvas in Threejs

Tags: three.js

This is a really simple question, but how do I place an object at the bottom of the canvas using Threejs? I could just manually set its position, but would this work across all screen sizes?

Comment: It's actually not a simple question. What camera are you using? What screen sizes do you want to support? Does you object need to be in world space or just view space? **What have you tried so far?** What isn't working about what you've tried? Please do some testing and see what you get. In Chrome, you can [simulate different device screen sizes using the developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/).

Comment: See the HUD in [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html).